How can I filter df “A” using as a condition a comparison to df “B”?
I’ve got 2 dataframes, dfA and dfB, with different shapes and with different orders. dfA is contained in dfB.
There are 3 columns in this example, “Job Title”, “Job Department” and “Job Salary”. dfA has missing values in the “Job Salary” column, so I’d like to get those values from dfB.
If the “Job Title” and “Job Department” are a match in between dfA and dfB, the “Job Salary” is the same too, so I can use the “Job Salary” from dbB to fill dfA.
For example, every “English Teacher” in “Teachers” department have salary X, but “English Teacher” from “Private Teachers” department have a different salary, though the title is the same.
However, I haven’t been able to find the code to do that yet.
My thought process was this one, though I think it’s entirely wrong:
condition_A = (dfA['Job Title'] == dfB['Job Title'])

condition_B = (dfA['Job Department'] == dfB['Job Department'])

dfA.loc[(condition_A) & (condition_B), 'Job Salary'] = dfB.loc[(condition_A) & (condition_B), 'Job Salary']

That attempt obviously didn’t work.
dataA = {
    'Job Title': ['ET', 'FT', 'ET', 'ST', 'ST'],
    'Job Department': ['T', 'T', 'PT', 'T', 'PT'],
    'Job Salary': [np.nan, 1500, 1000, np.nan, np.nan]
}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(dataA)

dataB = {
    'Job Title': ['ST', 'ET', 'RT', 'FT', 'ST', 'PT', 'ET'],
    'Job Department': ['T', 'T', 'PT', 'T', 'PT', 'T', 'PT'],
    'Job Salary': [2000, 800, 1700, 1500, 2500, 700, 1000]
}
dfB = pd.DataFrame(dataB)

Desired result (dfA missing values filled from dfB):
dataA = {
    'Job Title': ['ET', 'FT', 'ET', 'ST', 'ST'],
    'Job Department': ['T', 'T', 'PT', 'T', 'PT'],
    'Job Salary': [800, 1500, 1000, 2000, 2500]
}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(dataA)

Thanks in advance!

show us, don't tell us. Can you provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Will try to do that now, give me a minute. I’ll edit the post.

Still not reproducible... Use a dict and provide more data. Copying that messes up md data will take forever.

I finally managed to demonstrate it using a dictionary. Please let me know if further data or information is needed.

dfA = pd.merge(
    dfA,
    dfB,
    how="left",
    on=["Job Title", "Job Department"],
    suffixes=("_dropme", ""),
).drop(columns='Job Salary_dropme')

Results in the table as you describe apart from the last Job Salary value, which I assume if a mistake on your end as that Title-Department-Salary does not exist in the given examples for dfA and dfB.



Job Title
Job Department
Job Salary




ET
T
800


FT
T
1500


ET
PT
1000


ST
T
2000


ST
PT
2500




I think that might work. Could you kindly clarify what how and suffixes do?

No problem. The pd.merge with option how='left' essentially peforms a sql left join (where the left table is dfA). This preserves dfA dims.
When doing SQL-like joins there needs to be a unique key. In this case its the Job Title-Job Department tuple. The other columns are added in as part of the join.
Mainly, the two tables share the 'Job Salary' column - how can we represent them in one table if they have the same name? To solve this, the suffixes=("_dropme", "") column adds the suffixes to 'Job Salary' to keep column names unique.
Hope that helps!

Tysm for the help and explanation. Your solution worked. I can’t upvote because I don’t have reputation enough, but I checked your suggestion as the solution.

You can drop the column from dfA beforehand: dfA.drop('Job Salary', axis=1).merge(dfB, on=['Job Title', 'Job Department'], how='left'). Or: dfA[['Job Title', 'Job Department']].merge(dfB, on=['Job Title', 'Job Department'], how='left'). You won't need to set suffixes that way.

@ouroboros1 Neat trick! However, with that solution we would assume that whatever dfA salaries has, dfB has them as well - which I do suppose works in this particular (small) example.
The edge case that I'm unnecessarily thinking of here is where a salary in dfA is different to dfB but neither are null - which one would we take as the truth.

OP explicitly says that dfA and dfB will have the same salaries for non-NaN values. Otherwise, there might of course be a use for both columns side by side.

@ouroboros1 well I respectfully disagree - OP might have implicitly said that dfA and dfB salaries are the same when he mentioned that dfA is contained in dfB. Contained in this context might mean multiple things - one of which being contained across columns but not values.

OP writes: If the “Job Title” and “Job Department” are a match in between dfA and dfB, the “Job Salary” is the same too, so I can use the “Job Salary” from dbB to fill dfA. I don't see anything ambiguous about that statement.

The ambiguity for myself arises in the context leading up to that sentence when OP mentions dfA has missing values in the “Job Salary” column, so I’d like to get those values from dfB, which implies that the next match that OP talks about, i.e. your quote, relates to only the cases where dfA has missing salaries - leading to the ambiguity on cases where there is a match on key but the dfs have different salaries.

For a combination of “Job Title” and “Job Department” there can only be one “Job Salary”, and both dfA and dfB would have the same values if there weren’t NaN values in A. When I said dfA is contained in dfB, I meant that I could find every single entry of A in B, but in my case the real dataframes are not that simple, there are a lot more columns, and I only really needed the “Job Salary” info from B to complete A.
